# Xrandr configuration in .bashrc not running until I open a terminal?

Tags: xrandr

I have the following in my .bashrc file...

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# multi-monitor configuration
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output DP1 --off --output VGA1 --mode 1600x900 --pos 1920x0 --rotate normal
```

When I login, my monitors are mirrored and are at a bad resolution, making me believe this did not run. However, the first time I open a terminal after logging in, my monitors adjust the proper resolution and extend properly.

Why does this .bashrc file seem to be running only after I open a terminal? I was under the impression it runs when I login. How can I get it to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.bashrc` (as it name may suggest) is only executed on startup of a bash shell.

You have to edit `~/.profile` to apply changes to your graphical session. Note that this file is intended for setting environment variables and such. You'd better create a [startup script](https://askubuntu.com/q/814/6969) to accomplish this task.

Comment: Heh. I should have assumed that from the name. Got it fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Ya should mark Lekensteyn's post as the answer then